# What op-amp configuration would implement this behavior?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have a 0-5 V voltage input to a system but I want the voltage to be constant after 2 V. If I buffer it, the output will still be 0-5V but I need it to be 0-2V.

So basically the input/output relation must be:

0 -> 0
1 -> 1
1.5 -> 1.5
1.9 -> 1.9
2 -> 2
2.1 -> 2
2.5 -> 2
3 -> 2
4 -> 2
5 -> 2

A voltage divider solution will not give the above. How could it be implemented using an op-amp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way (but slow response), only a single +5V supply required.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEMcMB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

You may not need the second op-amp, it's just a buffer to reduce the output impedance.

Here is what happens if the signal is faster.. .

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> *how could that be implemented using an opamp?*

An [op-amp clipper circuit](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/op-amp-precision-positive-negative-clipper-using-lt6015-lt6016-lt6017.html) should work fine and be accurate. This circuit clips at 4.096 volts positive and 0 volts (for example): -

[image]

[image]

Here's another: -

[image]

This one appears to perform slightly better than the first (and the author says as much). [Link](https://btbm.ch/testing-the-op-amp-clipper-circuit/).

Comment: Oh thanks for the answer it is more work than I thought. Would that simplify the circuitry if the output goes to zero after input exceeding 2V? Because if so, I can also live with it. (I also dont need negative clipper the input is 0 to 5V)

Comment: at least the first circuit *requires* opamps without differential input voltage clamping diodes or it will perform poorly.

Comment: @user1999 just ignore op-amp U2 and its associated diode if you only want positive clipping and, as tobalt says, an extra diode across U1 would be beneficial if the signal changed rapidly.

Comment: @Andyaka " an extra diode across U1 " when you say across between which nodes you mean? also is dual supply must for this circuit to operate?

Comment: @user1999 OK, that idea won't work because of the configuration of the circuit so just ignore U2 and it's diode if you want a positive-only clipper.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do it with a diode connected to 1.3V (or 1.7V using a Schottky)?
It won't be as accurate as opamps, but it is simpler.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTGn4L.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>